# How do I to adjust the identation

Tags: html, css

How to ensure that the text does not exceed the gray border, and there is no scroll bar? I think that the problem is comming from the width of `<td class="message">`.

**Edit :** The bottom-border is already the border of `<td class="message">` to show its width.

[image]

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/eGVZx/3/

HTML

```
<div class="liste_posts">
  <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="message">
              <div class="topic_div"><p>Si vous êtes sur cette page, c'est parce que vous avez décidé de laisser tomber phpbb, ou autre, pour vous lancer dans l'aventure qu'est la création d'un forum. Et ça tombe bien, parce que justement, ici on va voir comment faire ça Smiley. Il faut, avant de commencer, que vous sachiez que je vais montrer comment réaliser une base que vous pourrez ensuite faire évoluer comme bon vous semblera.</p></div>
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.message{
    background-color: rgb(244, 238, 250);
}

.topic_div p {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Grey border? I don't see a grey border?

Comment: We need some context..

Comment: Maybe you need to set a width?

Comment: @putvande, it's a part of the whole code !

Comment: Maybe you should show the whole code?

Comment: @Babblo, I've tried to set width but it doesn't work, you can try that with the published fiddle.

Comment: @putvande, I don't think that you need that. That would be unclean to detect and repair the real issue !

Comment: I don't understand why that is not needed, you are talking about a border... but your code doesn't show any border. How are you expecting people to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be understanding your requirements; however, here is something which might be similar to what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/eGVZx/8/

```
.message{
    background-color: rgb(244, 238, 250);
}

.topic_div p {
    word-break: break-all;
    width: 80%;
    padding-right: 20%; 
}
```

This would allow for the "gray" section to cover the other 20% where the text is not. Needless to say, you can adjust the percentage indent as necessary to create enough room for the text area and gray area, which would sit over top.

Please provide more information if necessary. 
Hope this helps at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to indent the first line use the css `text-indent`. If you want to indent all lines use `padding-left` for a left indent.

As far as your text flowing out of your `<td>` you need to add a `max-width` to your `<td>` or the `div.topic_div` or just a static `width`.

////EDIT////

http://jsfiddle.net/eGVZx/6/

Comment: why setting width as `70%` doesn't work ?

Comment: Put the width on the wrong element on the last fiddle. Here ya go. http://jsfiddle.net/eGVZx/10/

Comment: but when resize the result container, the `<p>` width doesn't change, no ?

Comment: If you resize `.liste_posts` the `p` width will change if it has a % for a width.

Comment: Wow, you get a good answer and several responses from me and mark someone else's answer as correct. Wow.